# Resolving Template Overloads with Function Parameter Return Type

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, std-function, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to wrap several third-party library functions that use the C-style "Call - Allocate - Call Again" pattern (there should be a better name for this). For example:

```
int EnumerateFoo(float f, uint32_t* count, float* buf) {
    if (!buf) {
        *count = 3;
        return 0;
    }
    if (*count < 3) {
        cout << "buffer too small\n";
        return -1;
    }
    buf[0] = f;
    buf[1] = f + f;
    buf[2] = f * f;
    return 0;
}

// ...

uint32_t count = 0;
int ret = EnumerateFoo(3.14f, &count, nullptr);
if (ret) return ret;
float* buf = new float[count];
ret = EnumerateFoo(3.14f, &count, buf);
if (ret) return ret;
```

I'd like to wrap this so that functions like this can be called much more concisely.  Ideally, I'd be able to call them as, e.g.:

```
vector<float> vec = WrapEnumerate(EnumerateFoo, 3.14f);
```

The closest I've gotten though is something like the following (using `std::bind` since the count/buffer parameters aren't always at the same parameter indices):

```
template<class T>
vector<T> EnumToVec(function<int(uint32_t*,T*)> fn) {
    vector<T> ret;
    uint32_t count = 0;
    if(fn(&count, nullptr))
        return vector<T>();
    ret.resize(count);
    if(fn(&count, ret.data()))
        return vector<T>();
    return ret;
}

// ...

auto vec = EnumToVec<float>(bind(
    EnumerateFoo, 3.14f, placeholder::_1, placeholder::_2));
```

This works well enough, but unfortunately a few of the library functions have `void` return types instead of `int`. I've tried creating an overload of `EnumToVec` that replaces the `function<int...` with `function<void...` but the compiler says the call is ambiguous.

**How do I create an overload that is disambiguated only by the return-type of the function parameter?** *Note this is NOT about overloading based on function return type only, which I know you can't do.*  I know I could just create a `EnumToVecNoReturn` alternate, but I was hoping there was a simpler way. I suspect SFINAE may apply here, but I'm unfamiliar with those technoques.

Experiment is here: https://ideone.com/IDygru

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value returned by `std::bind` can be converted to a `std::function` but isn't a `std::function`.

It's a sort of egg and chicken problem.

When you call

```
EnumToVec<float>(std::bind(EnumerateFoo, 3.14f, _1, _2));
```

you have that the compiler can't choose between the `void` and the `int` version because `EnumVec` doesn't receive a `std::function` value; and doesn't receive a `std::function` because the compiler can't choose between a the `void` and the `int` version.

A possible solution is explicitly create the correct `std::function` and the call `EnumToVec`

```
std::function<int(uint32_t *, float *)> ef { std::bind(EnumerateFoo, 3.14f, _1, _2) };
auto vecFoo = EnumToVec(ef);
```

Observe that you can avoid to explicit the `float` template parameter because can be deduced by `ef`.

Another possible solution is give away `std::function`, receive the executable as generic typename and SFINAE enable/disable the two function according the type returned by the functional

Something as

```
template <typename T, typename F>
auto EnumToVec (F const & fn)
   -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<
         decltype(fn(std::declval<std::uint32_t*>(), std::declval<T*>())),
         int>, std::vector<T>>
 { //....^^^ int here
   vector<T> ret;
   uint32_t count = 0;
   if(fn(&count, nullptr))
      return vector<T>();
   ret.resize(count);
   if(fn(&count, ret.data()))
      return vector<T>();
   return ret;
 }


template <typename T, typename F>
auto EnumToVec (F const & fn)
   -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<
         decltype(fn(std::declval<std::uint32_t*>(), std::declval<T*>())),
         void>, std::vector<T>>
 { // ...^^^^  void here
   vector<T> ret;
   uint32_t count = 0;
   fn(&count, nullptr);
   ret.resize(count);
   fn(&count, ret.data());
   return ret;
 }
```

So you can call

```
auto vecFoo = EnumToVec<float>(std::bind(EnumerateFoo, 3.14f, _1, _2));
```

but explicating the `T` typename because isn't deduced.